# Possible to alternate between two loops

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop

I'm trying to create a loop that allows me to do this:

```
<div>

    <div 1> first post from the "featured" category </div> 

    <div 2> first post not from the "featured" category </div> 

    <div 3> second post from the "featured" category </div> 

    <div 4> second post not from the "featured" category </div> 

    <div 5> third post from the "featured" category </div> 

    <div 6> third post not from the "featured" category </div> 

</div>
```

These posts are all from the same post type.
Is it possible to do so with `wp_query`?

Comment: You'll need two queries. `WP_Query` has [limited sorting power](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) so it won't interweave two categories like that. Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 3):

You need two queries for this. Let's say the ID of the featured category is 5. Then you set up two queries retrieving 3 posts each:

```
$query1 = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '5', 'posts_per_page' => 3  ) );

$query2 = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '-5', 'posts_per_page' => 3  ) );
```

Now you have two sets of posts with a maximum of three items. There might be less. I don't know how you want to handle that situation, but assuming you want an even amount of posts you would loop through them like this:

```
while ($query1->have_posts() && $query2->have_posts()) {
  ...
  $query1->the_post()
  echo '<h1>' . the_title() '</h1>';
  echo '<div class="post-content">' . the_content() . '</div>'
  ...
  $query2->the_post()
  echo '<h1>' . the_title() '</h1>';
  echo '<div class="post-content">' . the_content() . '</div>'
  ...
  }
```

Note: I didn't test this code, so beware of typos and so on.